# A proof of $dim(W) < dim(V)$ if $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Definition: A family $\alpha$ is a base of a vector space $V$ if $[\alpha] = V$ and $\alpha$ is l.i. ($[\alpha]$ is the set of all linear combinations of vector of $\alpha$).
>
> Proposition (1): Suppose $\alpha$ is a finite family such that $[\alpha] = V$. Then exists subfamily $\beta$ of $\alpha$ such that $\beta$ is a base of $V$.
>
> Proposition (2): If $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$, then dim(W) < dim(V).

Proposition (1) is OK. I can't understand the last assertion in the following proof of (2):

"Let $n = dim(V)$ and choose a base $\beta = w_1, w_2,\dots, w_m$ of $W$. Because $W$ is proper, exists $w\in V\setminus W$. So the family $\beta ' = w_1, w_2,\dots, w_m, w$ is l.i. and by proposition 1, $m+1 \le n$, which proves 2."

I can't see why (1) implies $m+1\le n$.

Comment: from the claim that if $W$ is a subspace (not nec. proper) of $V$, then $dim(W) \le dim(V)$. It relies heavily on that claim. See if you can take this hint and work it out.

Comment: I think it could be a wrong LaTeX citation or some other typo. Aren't there more propositions? E.g. "If $U$ is a set of linearly independent vectors in $V$, then [$U$ can be extended to a base, hence] $|U|<\dim V$."

Comment: @Berci, now I think that was the case. After this prop. 1, there is another that says: "if $\alpha$ is a finite family such that $[\alpha] = V$ then any other l.i. family $\beta$ is such that $|\beta| \le |\alpha|$."

Comment: So is the question still open, or have you solved it? If the latter, you can answer your own question below. :)